# Super User's Internet Explorer tagging convention

Tags: discussion, tags

So far questions on Super User are being branched off into separate tagging conventions with regards to Internet Explorer.

- ie
- internet-explorer
- ie8, internet-explorer-8, etc.

I am posting this to try and head this off early so that we can nail down a standard convention for these class of posts.

My personal preference would be for internet-explorer with version specific questions being internet-explorer-8, etc.

Comment: appears it's time to revisit this.

Answer (score 7):

IMHO tags should be used as follows:

- internet-explorer: general IE questions
- ie`X`: if specific browser version

If an ie`X` tag is on a post, internet-explorer should be too.

The reason for this is because `ie6`, `ie7` and so on are just as popular of search terms as `Internet Explorer`.

Comment: Agreed that ieX terms should be used. When I need IE specific references I always use that naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since this was brought up, so I'm bumping this back to the front page to take the community's temperature.

Current tag usage:

```
Tag                   SU  SO  SF
[internet-explorer]   224 ~3k  67
[internet-explorer-6]  23   7   0
[internet-explorer-7]  23  23   0
[internet-explorer-8] 145  48   0
[ie]                    0 418  26
[ie6]                   0 746  14
[ie7]                   0 654   9
[ie8]                   0 628  51
```

So Super User currently has it a bit backwards from SO & SF.

I have no personal preference for which tags get used.  Considerations:

- [ieX] tags are shorter...
- [internet-explorer] + [ieX] tags are slightly confusing...
- [internet-explorer-X] tags are easy to search on with the ~ wildcard... (a URL like https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer~ gets all tags in one shot; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ie~ only grabs the [ie] tag)
- synchronizing the tag conventions might help tag maintainers keep their sanity, since the "wrong tags" keep getting recreated anytime one of these questions is migrated to/from SU...

Comment: (Also, SO/SF might want to do a retag on [ie] => [internet-explorer].)

Comment: (also also, the "ie~" appears to be a bug.  note to self, post a bug report.)

Comment: @json: for whatever reason SU went the complete opposite way.  like since august '09.  which is why i'm bumping this.

Comment: Interesting... SU always seemed a little backwards.

Comment: We also use windows-7 and not win-7 just because it's shorter, so I'd prefer the full blown internet-explorer-X

Comment: @ivo: to be fair, the length difference here isn't a mere 50%, it's an order of magnitude.  but the more interesting question to me is whether keeping tags consistent across the trilogy is desirable...

Comment: @quack: I don't think that you should cater to the community formed on the site. If SU people like their tags as full blown names, let it be. As for programmers, we are lazy.

Comment: @gnome: nice edit.  gawd, i hope you didn't do that by hand...

Comment: @quack: I had one problem, and then I used regex.